# UIAlertView - make both input fields secure

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

Is it possible to have both input types of `UIAlertView` as password type ?
I am implementing **Change password** functionality and was wondering if this is possible.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Change password" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Change password", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].placeholder = @"New password";
[alert textFieldAtIndex:1].placeholder = @"Confirm password";
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].secureTextEntry = YES;
[alert textFieldAtIndex:1].secureTextEntry = YES;
```

Comment: Correcto :) Will accept your answer in 9 minutes as per StackOverflow.

Comment: On a different subject, is it possible to change the frame of these input fields ?